# Isotope resizising container images when applied to squarespace shop

Tags: squarespace

I am working on a squarespace shop that is displaying equal sized images.
I have added Isotope to the shop webpage for sorting and it has resized all of the images.
Is there an easy way to fix this?

Squarespace without isotope:
[image]

Squarespace with isotope:
[image]

This is the isotope code I added to the page header:

```
<script>
    var elem;
    var iso;
    window.onload = function(){
        elem = document.querySelector('.list-grid');
        iso = new Isotope( elem, {
        //options
        percentPosition: true,
        itemSelector: '.grid-item',
        layoutMode: 'fitRows',
        containerStyle: null,
        resize: false,
        fitRows: {
            equalheight: true,
            gutter: 30
        },
        getSortData: {
          name: '.grid-title'
        }
    });
  }

  function myFunction(name) {
    iso.arrange({ sortBy: name });
  }
</script>


Here is the GRID html that I can see in the inspector on Chrome on the website (https://www.bloominfun.com.au/shop):

    <div class="products-flex-container">
  <div class="
      list-grid
      
    ">

    <div class="grid-item hentry author-esther-matthews post-type-store-item article-index-1 sold-out sqs-product-quick-view-button-hover-area is-loaded" id="thumb-aeschynanthus-black-pagoda-lipstick-plant" data-item-id="638d7869e784783f3547e01d" data-controller="ProductListImageLoader" data-controllers-bound="ProductListImageLoader">
      <a href="/shop/p/aeschynanthus-black-pagoda-lipstick-plant" aria-label="Aeschynanthus ‘Black Pagoda’ (Lipstick Plant)" class="grid-item-link">
      </a>

      <figure class="grid-image" data-animation-role="image" data-test="plp-grid-image">
        <div class="grid-image-wrapper has-hover-img">


          <img data-src="https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/633d431ca8ef9d31ac428403/1670216040701-HSTA1368VGFYAQJK2N48/Black+pagoda1+-+Copy.jpg" data-image="https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/633d431ca8ef9d31ac428403/1670216040701-HSTA1368VGFYAQJK2N48/Black+pagoda1+-+Copy.jpg" data-image-dimensions="3024x4032" data-image-focal-point="0.5,0.5" alt="Black pagoda1 - Copy.jpg" data-load="false" class="grid-item-image
            grid-image-cover" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; object-position: 50% 50%; object-fit: cover;" data-parent-ratio="0.8" data-image-resolution="750w" src="https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/633d431ca8ef9d31ac428403/1670216040701-HSTA1368VGFYAQJK2N48/Black+pagoda1+-+Copy.jpg?format=750w">




          <img data-src="https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/633d431ca8ef9d31ac428403/1670216040942-WZ75UU2F5NTZSYS6J5B6/Black+pagoda2+-+Copy.jpg" data-image="https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/633d431ca8ef9d31ac428403/1670216040942-WZ75UU2F5NTZSYS6J5B6/Black+pagoda2+-+Copy.jpg" data-image-dimensions="3024x4032" data-image-focal-point="0.5,0.5" alt="Black pagoda2 - Copy.jpg" data-load="false" class="grid-item-image
            grid-image-hover" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; object-position: 50% 50%; object-fit: cover;" data-parent-ratio="0.8" data-image-resolution="750w" src="https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/633d431ca8ef9d31ac428403/1670216040942-WZ75UU2F5NTZSYS6J5B6/Black+pagoda2+-+Copy.jpg?format=750w">




        </div>
      </figure>

      <section class="grid-meta-wrapper" data-animation-role="content">
        <div class="grid-main-meta">

          <div class="grid-title" data-test="plp-grid-title">
            Aeschynanthus ‘Black Pagoda’ (Lipstick Plant)
          </div>


          <div class="grid-prices" data-test="plp-grid-prices">



            <div class="product-price">
              $17.00
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-meta-status" data-test="plp-grid-status">

          <div class="product-mark sold-out">Sold Out</div>
        </div>
      </section>
```

Comment: I tried using custom CSS on grid-items and and some other elements and I couldn't find anything that worked. I could make differences to the size of the enclosing DIV this way but not the actual size of the image.

Comment: Are you able to provide your html div class "grid" and your css. That would help investigate the issue

Comment: That is auto generated by squarespace. I can see then end result by going to the inspector when viewing the website: https://www.bloominfun.com.au/shop